# Azure Confusion - Guide to Python in Azure - Where do I start?

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint

Help!

I have a small python script that logins to a website, downloads a bundle of files and then saves these files to a Sharepoint site for use by others. There are multiple files to this and several required python imports.

I'd like to move this to Azure so I can put this thing on a schedule to run periodically so I can forget about it (and have the script send notification or otherwise). Actually there are other scripts I would also like to put on a schedule.

I'm somewhat baffled in where to start doing this on Azure. I have an Azure account with some free credit but beyond that confused as what Azure service this should be built on.

Google searching is not helping as all I get is bundle of buzzwords that are not really helping.

Looking for some pointers in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend looking at Azure Functions with Timer Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Gaurav Mantri, you can use [Azure functions' Timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python) where the function is run on a schedule. Alternatively, for codeless automated workflows, you can even opt for [Azure logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) which provide many connectors that are performed just by constructing a workflow.

**REFERENCES:** [Connect to SharePoint from Azure Logic Apps - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sharepoint)